# Consume and decode protobuf messages in cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, protocol-buffers, decode

I want to consume pub/sub messages from a topic (GCP cloud pub/sub) and then somehow load in to a database.

I've decided to create a cloud function with a pub/sub trigger connected to the topic I want to consume messages from. The data is sent in a protobuf format.

When writing some lines of python code, I'm able to decode the message using my .proto file and parse the message using 'ParseFromString'

```
import person_pb2 #This is the file generated from my .proto file with the format of the data

from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()

    def callback(message):
        person = person_pb2.List()
        person.ParseFromString(message.data)
        print(person)
    
    future = subscriber.subscribe(f'projects/my_project/subscriptions/test-sub', callback)
    try:
        future.result()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        future.cancel()
```

Below is the function being executed in my cloud function. It's currently working but as you can see I'm not using the person_pb2 generated from my .proto file.

```
def decode_pubsub(event, context):

    import base64

    print(f'message id: {context.event_id}, timestamp: {context.timestamp}')
    data = event['data']
    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data).decode('utf-8')
    print(decoded_data)
```

So now to the question:

In the first scenario the type of the message is <class 'bytes'> I'm decoding with ParseFromString
In the second scenario the type of the message is <class 'str'> I'm decoding with Base64

Is there no need to use the .proto file to decode the message within the cloud function?